# How to ensure that you retrieve all permission attributes (including ACLs) of a file or folder from the shell?

Tags: terminal, permission, filesystem, extended-attributes

I would like to retrieve ALL permissions (including ACLs) and attributes of files and folders (both) from a folder and its accompanying files on a drive.

Most frequently one sees `ls -le` being used to get such data, however are there attributes, including extended attributes, that this misses?

So far the most comprehensive info I've been able to pull up is via:

```
ls -laeO@tr $FILE
xattr -l $FILE
```

Are there any additional commands that are necessary to retrieve all possible permissions and extended attributes that a file or folder could possibly have set for it in macOS?